# Insertion Sorting implementation difference

Tags: java, sorting

I have seen the implementation for insertion sort in two different ways as below,

Method 1:

```
        for (int out = 1; out < numbers.length; out++) {

        int temp = numbers[out];
        int in = out - 1;
        while (in >= 0 && numbers[in] > temp) {

            numbers[in + 1] = numbers[in];
            numbers[in] = temp;
            in--;
        }

        }
```

Method 2:

```
int S[] = { 20, 25, 10};
    int N = S.length;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        int j = i - 1;
        int temp = S[i];

        while (j >= 0 && S[j] > temp) {
        S[j + 1] = S[j];
        j--;
        }

        S[j + 1] = temp;
    }
```

But i can not understand the reason why the swaping is in out of the while loop in the second approach? Is there a reason for have it out side the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

The two versions are functionally equivalent. The latter simply avoids doing some unnecessary work.

In the first version, the following assignment

```
numbers[in] = temp;
```

will get undone by the next iteration of the loop, if the loop continues. The second version takes note of this fact, and doesn't bother with reinstating `temp` until the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly it is both the same, but in the first one, you´r just writing the temp number instantly to the one you copied to the element[in + 1]. in the second one, you wait until you´r while loop has finished. So it is just saving some time.